# Implementing Sets in Fortran

Tags: fortran, gfortran

Is there a way to implement sets in Fortran? Like there is a set data type in python, or like there is the Set class in C++ STL.

This is what I mean:

C++ sets:

```cpp
set <int, greater <int> > myset;
```

Python sets:

```py
myset = set()
```

I have tried looking at a few books and other resources, but I have not found any mention of sets.

Comment: There is no reason why the methods used for implementing sets in C++ STL should not work in Fortran as well. You just have to count with the lack of templates in Fortran. Or just use the methods you learned in the CS class you mention. It will be a hard work. There are implementations of other types of container in FLIBS http://fortranwiki.org/fortran/show/FLIBS so you can get some inspiration. The project appears to be active with one commit less then an hour ago in the trunk. Note that external resource recommendation is off-topic here.

Comment: @VladimirF, I will try to replicate the C++ template for sets which I have learned and try to implement them here. My question was there because there are existing implementations for sets in other languages, and I did not want to waste my time on implementing sets if there is already some way to do that in fortran

Comment: You can certainly wrap the C++ object and call it from Fortran. You just have to do the instantiation for the actual type in C++ and only after that call it from Fortran. That is what I would do if I needed a set container in practice. But fortunately I don't.

Comment: Yes, that is what I planned on doing initially, however, we need to write all of the code for our project in Fortran. I will probably have to change the logic so that it does not require sets. Or use arrays in some way such that it acts like an array.

Comment: I think the lack of popular container libraries (e.g. based on generics) is really one shortcoming of Fortran... In addition to wrapping C++ STL or using FLIBS above, this code might also be of some reference (I haven't used it myself, so just FYI) https://github.com/SCM-NV/ftl https://github.com/SCM-NV/ftl/blob/master/tests/ftlHashSetTests.F90 https://github.com/SCM-NV/ftl/wiki/ftlHashSet

Comment: Thank you for the resources @roygvib. I might just use one of these libraries (including FLIBS)